# Return JSON from API method

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using ASP.net Core web api (c#) here

I have a JSON string as:

```
{
   "userId":321,   
   "account":"new  
   "fname":"Adam",
   "lname":"Silver" 
   "features":[
      {
         "available":true,
         "status":open,
         "admin":false        
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to test this data in my angular code so wanted to hardcode this into my API; then I want my API to return this back. What I am finding it hard is how to return this. Shall I return this as a string or need to parse it?

I have this method in my API:

```
[HttpGet]        
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
{
     return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

Do I need to represent this into string or parse it someway?

Comment: Why are you finding it hard what's the issue here that you are facing not clear from the question

Comment: There's no such thing as "a JSON". JSON is a text format for sending data across the wire. You either have an object, or you have a string. If you have an object, use `return Json(obj)`. If you have a string, set the content type header to "application/json".

Comment: Sorry I am using asp.net core web api and then using angular as the front end for consuming this. Like the above default api is returning value1 and value2. I wanted to know how can I format my above json to return in the same manner.

Comment: Create a class structure that represents the JSON structure you want to return. Then create an instance of that class, and return it from your action method. Change the return type of your method to match what you're returning.

Comment: Mason is right. Forget about creating the JSON directly within Web API. Create an object with the correct structure, and return it. Web API will serialise it to JSON automatically for you.

Comment: @mason Thanks mason. I wanted to know if there is a simpler way of doing so as this i just temporary. I wanted to test a piece of functionality so wanted to hardcode this.

Comment: You could use an anonymous object for brevity.

Comment: Or you can use one of the many free tools around which will [turn your JSON into a class structure instantly](http://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: P.S. the JSON in your question has some syntax errors which you'll need to correct before you can do anything with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid. We need to correct it. [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) can be helpful for that. I took your JSON and corrected the syntax errors until I got this:

```
{
   "userId": 321,   
   "account": "new",
   "fname": "Adam",
   "lname": "Silver",
   "features":[
      {
         "available": true,
         "status": "open",
         "admin": false        
      }
   ]
}
```

Then I need to generate a C# class structure to represent this JSON. I could manually create it, but the excellent [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) can generate it for me quickly. I fed this JSON into and received the following classes back:

```
public class Feature
{
    public bool available { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public bool admin { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public string account { get; set; }
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public string lname { get; set; }
    public List<Feature> features { get; set; }
}
```

I put these class definitions into my application. Then I need to modify my action method to create an instance of this RootObject class (you should change the name to actually match what it's intended for).

```
[HttpGet]        
public ActionResult<RootObject> Get()
{
    // Create an instance of our RootObject and set the properties
    var myRootObject = new RootObject();
    myRootObject.userId = 321;
    myRootObject.account = "new";
    myRootObject.fname = "Adam";
    myRootObject.lname = "Silver";
    myRootObject.features = new List<Feature>();

    // Create an instance of a feature and set its properties
    var feature = new Feature();
    feature.available = true;
    feature.status = "open";
    feature.admin = false;

    // Add the new feature to the features collection of our RootObject    
    myRootObject.features.Add(feature);

    // Return the instance of our RootObject
    // The framework will handle serializing it to JSON for us
    return myRootObject;
}
```

Note that I changed the signature of your method. I made it no longer accept an IEnumerable because it wasn't clear why you had that. And I changed it to return an ActionResult after checking Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please find correct JSON format for above one:

```
{
    "userId": 321,
    "account": "new",
    "fname": "Adam",
    "lname": "Silver",
    "features": [{
        "available": true,
        "status": "open",
        "admin": false
    }]
}
```

you can use below class in your web API to pass respective data

```
public class Feature
{
    public bool available { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public bool admin { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public string account { get; set; }
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public string lname { get; set; }
    public List<Feature> features { get; set; }
}
```

then at the end, while returning data, convert the respective class object into JSON by serializing that into JSON format.

Hope it will fulfill your requirement.

Comment: How will it return in serilaize/return in the format of my json

Comment: @karen You would create an instance of the RootObject, then return that instance from your action method. The framework handles serialization for you.

Comment: and where shall I assign the values to this.

Comment: before returning data serialize instance of the RootObject into Json format as below.


                   string json = String.Format(RealJavaScriptConvert.SerializeObject( instance of the RootObject));

   Webrequest.Respond(Webrequest.ContentTypes.JSON, json, false);

Comment: @ChiragGohil I think you should edit that into your question. Show the instance creation and you should return it from the action method.

Comment: that will be like 

`RootObject obj = new RootObject();`
add your values in obj and 
`string json = String.Format(RealJavaScriptConvert.SerializeObject(obj)); Webrequest.Respond(Webrequest.ContentTypes.JSON, json, false);
`
is that what you were expecting @mason?

Comment: Not really. Your first statement is good, but why the string formatting, and what is RealJavaScriptConvert, and why use WebRequest? What you need to do is simple: create an instance of the object, populate the properties of the object, and return it from the action method.

Comment: @ChiragGohil ASP.NET handles the serialisation automatically. All you have to do is `return Ok(obj);`, something like that. If you've worked with Web API for more than 5 minutes you would know this?

Comment: I got it now the only thing is when I try to add features it says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"  I did RootObject obj = new RootObject();  Feature feature = new Feature(). Then after populating rootobject and feature when I try to add feature to the rootobject as obj.features.add(feature) it throws above error.

Comment: Yes,  RealJavaScriptConvert is cutom class created in my application for serialization. Sorry, my bad. in web API if the return type is void then we can user above Webrequest to return JSON data. @mason.
and what you are saying is absolutely right. :-)

Comment: You shouldn't assume when assisting someone that they have access to your custom source code. Also, it makes no sense to have void as the return type from your action method. And there would be no reason to generate a WebRequest.....

Comment: @karen, you need to create an instance of  `public List<Feature> features { get; set; } ` as well.

Answer (score -1):

Putting the comments into an answer:
If you are using ActionResult, I'll assume you are using asp.net mvc.  What you want is JsonResult.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        return new JsonResult
        {
            Data = new
            {
                userId = 321,
                account = new
                {
                    fname = "Adam",
                    lname = "Silver",
                    features = new object[]{
                    new
                {
                    available = true,
                    status = "open",
                    admin = false
                }
                }
                }
            },
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
    }
```

Comment: No, turns out it's ASP.NET Core Web API, which _does_ have an `ActionResult`

Comment: I specifically held off on answering until I was sure what framework was being used. If a question isn't clear, then wait until it's clear before attempting an answer. If you have enough reputation to comment, then you can work with the asker to obtain any clarifications needed.